# Links internos ajudam no ranqueamento do Google?

Tags: google, seo

Gostaria de saber se  link building interno em um blog, ajudam a ranquear no Google?

Se eu tiver um blog e cada post que fizer, eu linkar para um ou dois post durante o artigo. Isso ajuda a fazer esses posts ranquearem no Google?

Answer (score 0):

Sem dúvida se o seu link building interno for bem feito ele irá ajudar sim seu SEO, no entanto, não posso lhe afirmar que isso lhe ajudará a rankear melhor.

Acredito que será uma consequência natural um melhor rankeamento, caso o link direcione para um artigo relacionado e mantenha o interesse do usuário no assunto, a maioria dos blogs "bem sucedidos" utilizam dessa estratégia.

Esse [post](http://www.agenciamestre.com/seo/aumente-pagerank-links-internos/) utiliza muito o link building para explicar como aumentar o pageRank de sua página utilizando essa estratégia.

Answer (score 0):

Os links internos ajudam a informar ao Google quais páginas internas do seu site são mais relevantes, além de também ajudar o cliente final na usabilidade e navegação do seu site.

Se seu site tem uma boa navegabilidade além de um conteúdo bem organizado e atraente, consequentemente o usuário também irá ficar mais tempo nele, e está ai tembém outro fator de ranqueamento utilizado pelo Google.